# get_children() Not Working with orderby Parameter

Tags: posts, pages, get-posts, get-children

I am trying to use the `orderby` parameter in the `get_children` function as below:

```
$navigation = get_children(array(
  'post_parent' => $parent->ID,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order'
));
```

But it is having no effect on the result; it is still ordering by the default creation date.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you sure you need this specific function? Documentation (both Codex and inline) is verrry confusing. And it supposedly fetches things like attachments, which probably aren't relevant for navigation...

Try this:

```
get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $parent->ID,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
) );
```

Answer (score 4):

The `'orderby'` argument should work with `get_children()` because `get_children()` is really just a wrapper around `get_posts()` with a different set of defaults. The menu order refers to the *Order* specified in the **Page Attributes** meta box when editing a Page... not to the order you've sorted a custom menu into.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$args` in `get_children`, but ensure you also specify the post ID that you want to retrieve children from, even if it is the current page children you want

```
get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

Comment: How does this address the question? The OP claims that the order is still by creation date even though the original code has an `orderby` parameter?